# One value entered into one box will update all the boxes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Whenever i put a value into the first entry box it updates all the entry boxes is there any way to change this so each entry box is independent.

```
import tkinter
gui = tkinter.Tk()

num1e = int()
num2e = int()
num3e = int()
num4e = int()
num5e = int()
num6e = int()
num7e = int()

def Find():
    pass

gui.geometry("450x450+500+300")

num1 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num1e).pack()
num2 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num2e).pack()
num3 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num3e).pack()
num4 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num4e).pack()
num5 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num5e).pack()
num6 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num6e).pack()
num7 = tkinter.Entry(gui, bd = 5, width = 1, textvariable = num7e).pack()

Sb = tkinter.Button(gui, text ="Find 8th", command = Find).pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that the widget `.pack` method returns `None`, so all your `num1`, `num2` etc variables contain `None`. If you need a reference to those widgets you need to create them and pack them in two steps, eg, `num1 = tkinter.Entry(gui,...)` `num1.pack()`

Answer (score 2):

`int()` is `0`

```
>>> int()
0
```

So the code is passing `0` as `textvariable` to `tkinter.Entry` initializer. (all the same value; which cause all refer same variable - Tkinter accepts not only `XXXVar` object but also `int`/`str`)

The following lines:

```
num1e = int()
num2e = int()
num3e = int()
num4e = int()
num5e = int()
num6e = int()
num7e = int()
```

should be:

```
num1e = tkinter.IntVar()
num2e = tkinter.IntVar()
num3e = tkinter.IntVar()
num4e = tkinter.IntVar()
num5e = tkinter.IntVar()
num6e = tkinter.IntVar()
num7e = tkinter.IntVar()
```

Comment: if i do that all the boxes show up as zero is there way to do that and the boxes not show up as zero

Comment: @Steve, What boxes do you mean?

Comment: @Steve: What do you want the initial value of the Entry widgets to be? An empty string?

Comment: empty then i am planning to enter a number into each entry-widget and use it

Comment: @Steve, Then use `tkinter.StirngVar`. But you need to convert the value into `int` later if you want to do arithmetic operation. ex: `int(num5e.get()) + int(num6e.get())`

Comment: typo: that should be `tkinter.StringVar`